# Общий вопрос по скрэпингу инстаграма

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, beautiful-soup, instagram, web-scraping

Я начал учить питон месяц назад как хобби. Пытаюсь понять, как работает инстаграм скрапер.
https://github.com/rarcega/instagram-scraper

Если кто-то согласится немного объяснить мне принцип работы, буду очень благодарен.

### Есть несколько вопросов:

1. Зачем его делают консольным? Я попробовал использовать его в jupyter notebook и взять только нужный функционал, но возвращается None объект.

   ```
   username = 'аккаунт для скрабинга'
   login_user = 'логин'
   login_pass = 'пароль'
   retain_username = True
   maximum = 5
   latest=True
   media_types=['image']
   # template='{urlname}''{datetime}'

   s = instagram_scraper.InstagramScraper(username = username,
                login_user = login_user,
                login_pass = login_pass,
                retain_username = retain_username,
                maximum = maximum,
                latest = latest,
                media_types = media_types)
   # ss = s.get_csrf_token()
   # sss = ss.login_success()
   s.scrape().download()
   ```

   --- AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'download' ---

   В таком вот ключе хотелось бы использовать.

Я хочу сделать программку, которая будет заходить на выбранные аккаунты инстаграмма и проверять - есть ли новые фотки, если есть, грузить их в папку, если нет - ждать 5 минут и проверять еще раз.

Для такого, как мне кажется, достаточно requests и BeatifulSoup, т.к. скролить и разворачивать вниз не особо нужно.

Или можно взять selenium и BeatifulSoup для ситуаций, когда долго не проверял и фоточка ушла далеко вниз.

**НО, хотелось бы использовать уже готовые решения,  не выходит.**

---

2. В Консоли оно тоже не особо работает

   ```
   instagram-scraper акк_для_скраба -u логин -p пароль -m 2 -t 'image'
   ```

Находит акк, общее кол-во фоток, но качает только 1 фото с профиля.

Я что-то не так делаю или инстаграм опять поменял у себя внутри что-то?

---

3. Константы - https://github.com/rarcega/instagram-scraper/blob/wip/refactor/instagram_scraper/constants.py

На сколько я понял, в процессе работы программы, константы используются для получения нужных параметров (наборов урлов и прочего) в них и получения информации.

А выведены они отдельно для удобства изменения, в случае перемен на инстаграме.

**Вопрос:** Откуда берутся данные константы?

Я облазил весь код в пр осмотрщике в хроме и не нашел там такого. Лишь части совпадают. А, например, значения хэш - нет.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, пользуюсь instalooter ом, в нем все работает.
Также можно черезх Selenium решить данную проблему, токо медленно